# PDO Pagination - link to previous/next page not correct

Tags: php, pdo, hyperlink, pagination, target

I just added php pagination to my website but I don't manage to link to the correct pages.

**Background information:**

People can select a bike brand on the page "example.com/bikebrands.php".
So when they select "Bianchi", it opens the webpage "example.com/bikebrands/bianchi" with a list of all related news posts for that brand found in my database.

I had to set a target page to make the pagination work. I chose "/bikebrands" but that's not correct.
It should be:

```
$targetpage = "/bikebrands/**(echo row "bike brand" from database depending on the bike brand the visitor has selected)**?page=2";
```

So when someone opens:
`example.com/bikebrands/bianchi` and clicks "next", it should load `example.com/bikebrands/bianchi?page=2`

And when someone opens:
`example.com/bikebrands/trek` and clicks "next", it should load `example.com/bikebrands/trek?page=2`

The page `example.com/bikebrands/bianchi?page=2` exists so there's no problem with the url itself, it's just that I don't manage to link to that page.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming the brand is just another parameter could you not retrieve it using `$_GET['brand']` or whatever name it's been given?

```
$targetpage = "/bikebrands/" . $GET['brand'] . "?page=" . $next;
```

Comment: As simple as that. Thanks!